# Cordova project from .zip fails to build ios, tries to write to directory from other computer

Tags: ios, cordova

After successfully creating, building, and emulating Cordova's Hello World project, I unzipped the project folder that I am taking over from another developer on a different machine and saved it locally. While I can run the iOS app from XCode with the built project from the previous developer, I can't run the `$ cordova build ios` command successfully to rebuild it on my machine.

It give the following output:

```
The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
Write auxiliary files
```

When I run it in debug mode, I notice that both of these commands are trying to make a directory for the old dev's computer `(/Users/hisName/whereHePutIt/CordovaProject/stuffItIsTryingToBuild)` rather than one relative to my project folder `(/Users/myName/whereIPutMine/CordovaProject/stuffItIsTryingToBuild)`.

There is a lot of text to comb through, but it looks as though it is always failing while attempting to make a directory in `/Project/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build`

I am really stumped by this because I can't find any sort of setting or file in the project that tries to write anywhere but a path relative to my project file, and Android builds and emulates fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Android actually.  My home for sdk tools moved but the project still wanted to use the old sdk tools.

The solution I took was to remove the platform and then re-add it.  I am sure there is a way of going through the existing files and patching this, but everything you *should* need is in the plugin/ and www/ and where ever you elected to keep your assets.

If you do try this, make sure to create a backup before removing the platform -- it would be awful to lose changes that someone might have jammed down in the platform/ios folder.

Comment: I have considered that, and my only hesitation is that the first developers have fiddled with the platform builds and recompiling from the www completely will omit those changes. There is only one way to find out, however.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this issue under similar circumstances - unzipped a zipped copy of a iOS Cordova app from a coworkers computer to continue developing it, and found I could not successfully run the cordova build command.

I managed to get this to work by deleting the old "Debug-iphonesimulator" folders that had been zipped up with the rest of the project from the other computer, and then re-running the build command.

There were two folders that I deleted:
"../ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator"
and
"../ios/build/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator"

Hope this helps someone!